# saber si una frase tiene ciertas letras en orden o desorden Javascript

Tags: javascript

saben algún metodo o funcion para ver si en una palabra estan ciertas letra?
Por ejemplo

```
             if("CAMION TRANSPORTADO" contiene las letras "IMOC"){
               console.log("La palabra CAMION TRANSPORTADOR tienes las letras IMOC" )
             }
```

he leido del método index of, pero este solo evalua caracter por caracter con lo cual tendria que hacer un for loop, no sé si hay otra manera sin el uso de loops. agradezco su ayuda de antemano, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let arr1 = "CAMION TRANSPORTADO".split('');
let arr2 = "IMOC".split('');    
let intersection = arr1.filter(x => arr2.includes(x));
let unicos = [... new Set(intersection)];

if(unicos.length === arr2.length)
{
   console.log("La frase contiene todas las letras que se buscan");
}
else
{
   console.log("La frase no contiene todas las letras que se buscan");
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es transformar cada texto en arreglos guardándose dichos arreglos en las **variables** **arr1** y **arr2**. Posteriormente se hace una operación de intersección entre ambos arreglos, devolviéndose en la **variable intersection** los elementos que hay en común entre ambos arreglos, y después se eliminarían los elementos duplicados que existen en la **variable intersection**, guardándose finalmente todos los elementos en común y sin duplicados entre ambos arreglos en la **variable unicos**. Para finalizar se pregunta si el tamaño del **arreglo arr2** es igual al tamaño del **arreglo unico**, de ser iguales dichos tamaños entonces la frase contiene todos los caracteres que se buscan, de no ser iguales la frase no contiene todos los caracteres que se buscan.